# MySQL join a table to another table only if

Tags: mysql, if-statement, join

I have a little complicated query here. I have to select columns by names cant just user 'orders.*. because i have multiple columns from different tables with the same name.

What I'm trying to do is to select specific fields from orders,users,payment_methods_translation and join bank_accounts_translation only if the orders.payment_method_id = '3'

```
SELECT 
   orders.id as orderid,
   orders.final_total,
   orders.user_id,
   orders.auto_cancel,
   users.id as userid,
   users.first_name,
   payment_methods_translation.payment_method_id,
   payment_methods_translation.name 
FROM 
   orders,users, 
   payment_methods_translation
WHERE
   orders.id='$id' AND 
   orders.user_id = users.id AND
   orders.payment_method_id = payment_methods_translation.payment_method_id AND 
   orders.auto_cancel='1' 
JOIN 
   bank_accounts_translation ON (orders.payment_method_id='3' 
   AND orders.bank_id = bank_accounts_translation.bank_account_id)
```

But I get a mysql error. So how can I select all the fields from bank_accounts_translation only if orders.payment_method_id = '3' and orders.bank_id = bank_accounts_translation.bank_id

Comment: First `join`, then `where` (`select ... from ... join ... on ... where`).

Comment: Don't mix notations/standards.  use Inner Join syntax or use the , syntax.

Comment: Don't use comma join syntax. Period. And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Left join should do it...  I

- Refactored the code to use the current ANSI standards, you appear to be mixing them.
- used table aliases to improve readability.

LEFT JOIN says return all records from prior listed tables and only those that match the on criteria of the table being joined to.

```
SELECT O.id as orderid
      ,O.final_total
      ,O.user_id
      ,O.auto_cancel
      ,u.id as userid
      ,u.first_name
      ,PMT.payment_method_id
      ,PMT.name 
FROM orders O
INNER JOIN users U
   ON O.user_id = U.id 
INNER JOIN payment_methods_translation  PMT
   ON O.payment_method_id = PMT.payment_method_id 
LEFT JOIN bank_accounts_translation  BAT
   ON O.payment_method_id='3' 
  and O.bank_id = BAT.bank_account_id
WHERE O.id='$id' 
  and O.auto_cancel='1'
```

Comment: Unknown column 'u.id' in 'field list' - (and orders not Orders)

Comment: New code error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN bank_accounts_translation ON (orders.payment_method_id='3' AND orde' at line 18"

Comment: why do you have a `(` in there?  I see no `(` in my example.  As far as unknown column u.id in field list.... `users.id` is u.id  so I don't know how it could be unknown... it's in your query, so I'd have to see table structures for orders, users, payment_methods_translation and bank_accounts_translation.